# get a file from other remote server using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

anyone please suggest any remote server url which provide any file free, so i can get file on local using AJAX

```
var request=new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET','',false);
request.send();
console.log(request);
```

i want to access files which are publicly available using AJAX

Comment: can you provide your code ??

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi there is nothing wrong in code, i want any url which is publicly available for `GET` for `AJAX'

Comment: @JaromandaX yes that true, but i want any remote public url which i can access using `GET' of `AJAX`

Comment: @JaromandaX any protocol will be fine for me, i just want load file on local  from remote

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85484/discussion-between-girdhar-singh-rathore-and-jaromanda-x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url= http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=6600&country=AT&username=demo;

request.open('GET',url,false);
```